# change the location-permission dialog in iOS using google maps api v3

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-maps-api-3, permissions, dialog

I'm using the google maps javascript API v3 to display a map in a UIWebView.

However, when the dialog to ask for the user's permission for locationServices pops up, I get a pretty long, cryptic string. With CoreLocation, I can add a convenient message (purpose) to display another message, however, I cannot use CoreLocation (for various reasons) as the webpages asks for the permission although "the app may already have it".

How can I change this dialog's text to something more user friendly?

thanks in advance!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont understand why you can not use the CoreLocation service since the permission is granted to an app level, not to a domain/url, even if you use it from a webview already loaded before. Therefore, asking the permission from CoreLocation will resolve your problem and AFAIK will not introduce a duplicated message.

Besides that, I dont think you have a way to customize this message. The javascript API do not provide such customization, and you could even try to dive into the private APIs for the Webview to check if there exists a method requiring this info, but I guess that you will end up using CoreLocation and you will find problems with the AppStore reviewing process.

Once again, if you explain why you can not use CoreLocation we will be able to better understand the problem and look for a workaround.

Comment: I cannot explain why, but I already used the CoreLocation API and it didn't work, I always got this message. And yes, I also think there is no way to customize that.

Comment: You'll get the bounty for your effort

Comment: Woow! I think I dont deserve it but anyway thanks! I hope you find a solution!